# Traduzir mysql_query para PDO "UPDATE * SET... WHERE..."

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

Olá, recentemente comecei a traduzir os meus sites para PDO por motivos óbvios.
No entanto esse está me dando um pouco de dor de cabeça.

```
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("banco") or die(mysql_error());

$id1 = $_GET['id'];
$lat1 = $_GET['lat'];
$lon1 = $_GET['lon'];
$info1 = $_GET['info'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hora1 = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela SET lat='$lat1', lon='$lon1', info='$info1', hora='$hora1' WHERE id='$id1'");
    header ("Location: painel.php");
```

Esse código é relativamente simples, no entanto não estou conseguindo traduzi-lo.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados e seleciona-lo:

```
$sql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', "user", "pass");
```

Para executar o query:

```
sql->query(UPDATE tabela SET lat='$lat1', lon='$lon1', info='$info1', hora='$hora1' WHERE id='$id1');
```

Comment: obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para estabelecer uma conexão com um banco de dados utilizando PDO é necessário definir a string de conexão e passá-la para uma instância PDO, conforme exemplificação a seguir:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "banco";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // modo de erro do PDO para gerações de exceções
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE tabela SET lat='$lat1', lon='$lon1', info='$info1', hora='$hora1' WHERE id='$id1'";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // executa a query
    $stmt->execute();

    // mensagem de sucesso
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Na definição da string de conexão com o referido banco de dados, deve-se definir inicialmente o tipo do banco (neste caso, MySQL), os dados para autenticação no banco de dados (user e pass), além do banco de dados ao qual deseja-se estabelecer conexão (neste caso “banco”). No script apresentado, também foi definido o modo de erro do PDO para gerações de exceções sempre que quaisquer erros ocorrerem com as execuções das consultas no banco de dados.

Sempre que um script for finalizado, a conexão é automaticamente finalizada. Caso necessite finalizar a conexão antes, basta utilizar a seguinte instrução:   `$conn = null;`